# Computing the Singular Homology of the pair $(D^n,S^{n-1})$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence

I am trying to calculate the singular homology $H_q(D^n,S^{n-1}) \quad \forall q$.

With respect to the cases $q=0,1$ and  $n=1$ I have the following exact sequence 
$$\dots \rightarrow H_1(S^0) \rightarrow H_1(D^1) \rightarrow H_1(D^1,S^0) \rightarrow H_0(S^0)  \overset{i_{*0}}{\longrightarrow}  H_0(D^1) \rightarrow H_0(D^1,S^0)\rightarrow 0   $$
So, substituting the known homologies,

$$0 \rightarrow H_1(D^1,S^0) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \overset{i_{*0}}{\longrightarrow}  \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow H_0(D^1,S^0)\rightarrow 0 $$

If I were able to say that $i_{*0}$ is surjective I would be able to finish, because then I would conclude that, by sequence factorization, $H_0(D^1,S^0)=0$ and $H_1(D^1,S^0)=\mathbb{Z}$.

But I don't undestrand why is $i_{*0}$ surjective. 
Have you any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is a space, $H_0(X)$ is a free Abelian group consisting of a direct sum
of one copy of $\Bbb Z$ for each path component $C$ of $X$. This
$\Bbb Z$ has a canonical generator which I write as $[C]$.
In the map $H_0(X)\to H_0(Y)$ induced by $f:X\to Y$, $[C]$ maps to $[D]$
where $D$ is the path component of $Y$ containing $f(C)$.

Here $S^0$ has two path components and $D^1$ has one. Both the canonical
generators of $H_0(S^0)$ map to the canonical generator of $H_0(D^1)$.
Your map $i_0^*$ is therefore surjective.

Comment: is this true because a group  is cyclic if and only if it receives a surjective homomorphism from ℤ?

Comment: This is true for any coefficients, $H_0(X;G)$ is a direct sum of copies of $G$, one for each path component of $X$. The map $H_0(X;G) \to H_0(Y;G)$ will be surjective as long as each path component of $Y$ contains a point in the image of $X$.